# Assigning javascript variable to angularjs $scope.options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and have struggled with, what seems to be a simple task, and was hoping someone could help me.  The following code is in my controller.  I am dynamically generating the data that needs added to $scope.options.

This is what my data looks like:  `[{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];`

This works:

```
$scope.options = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
```

This doesn’t work:

```
var res = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
$scope.options = res;
```

Controller:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
                        if(i == (numberofitems-1)){

            teststuff += "{name:\""+jsonArray[i]["pondpitname"]+"\", id:"+jsonArray[i]["id"]+"}";
          }
          else
          {
            teststuff += "{name:\""+jsonArray[i]["pondpitname"]+"\", id:"+jsonArray[i]["id"]+"}, ";
          }


        }

        // teststuff looks like this [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }]; 
        var res = "["+teststuff+"]";


      $scope.options =  res;
```

Comment: What do you mean it "works" vs "does not work"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are constructing this array using strings?

Comment: Seems that your **res** variable is a string, not an array, maybe that's why it does not work

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  I'm not an expert with javascript either.  If there is a better way to construct the array, I would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Could you add what the contents of your `jsonArray` look like? Looks like you're trying to construct an array when you already have an array. What is your end goal? Sounds like you're trying to re-invent the wheel when there might be a much simpler solution

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to do here.  Angular works with JSON without modifications in most cases.  here, you seem to be taking an array, reading the values as strings, and trying to re-create a new array from that string.  was there something wrong with the original array that you couldn't use it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @maddob mentioned you are working with string.
If you want to convert json string into object, try `angular.fromJson`
But if you want directly generate object,
First i would recommend instead of for loop use `angular.forEach` (here is link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and before init `teststuff` or `res` as array

```
var result = [];
angular.forEach(jsonArray, function(value) {
   result.push({id: value.id, name: value.pondpitname});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS array map function to accomplish your task of converting an array of objects to another.

```js
var data = [
  { pondpitname: "test1", id: 1, blah:"meh", sfsa:"asf"  },
  { pondpitname: "test2", id: 2, blah:"meh", sfsa:"asf"  },
  { pondpitname: "test3", id: 3, blah:"meh", sfsa:"asf"  },
  { pondpitname: "test4", id: 4, blah:"meh", sfsa:"asf"  }
];

var result = data.map(o => { return { name: o.pondpitname, id: o.id }; });

console.log(result);
```